# Redirect http://www. old path to https://www. new path (1to1 redirect)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

Struggle with Redirect `http://www.` to new path and `https://www.`
Since we want to force `https://` it creates a chain from `http://www.` old path to `https://www.` old path to `https://www.` new path

`http://www.` old path -> `https://www.` old path -> `https://www.` new path
301 -> 301 -> 200

Anyone who can save my day? How do we solve this in .htaccess (apache)?

Comment: So you want to redirect `http://www.old.path` -- 301 --> `https://www.old.path` -- 301 --> `https://www.new.path`?

Comment: Do I want to redirect http:// www.old.path  -- 301 --> https:/ /www.new.path
Instead of: http:// www.old.path -- 301 --> https:// www.old.path -- 301 --> https:// www.new.path

1to1 instead of a chain. The issue is that I force https on all in .htaccess by following the best standard. But then, of course, it force the chain since it force it to add https.

It all works when it's  only http:// to https:// the issue is when it's http and old path that has changed path and now is under https://

If I just do 301's (no force= per page the other plain http to https pages starts to loop

Comment: Are you able to use HSTS to avoid the first redirect entirely (and if you can preload to ruin the day of anyone trying to MITM your site)

Comment: Yes of course we can add HSTS, either from Cloudflare or on server level. That is only effecting the browser though? not a GET request by a bot such as googlebot if I'm not wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new domain name:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example-old.com
  Redirect 301 / https://www.example-new.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example-new.com
  DocumentRoot /your_document_root
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to redirect from one folder to another:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect 301 /old-path https://www.example.com/new-path
  DocumentRoot /your_document_root
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Will test this later on, understand the logic but it also means I need to maintain it everytime a new page is added to the website. Then it also needs to be added to <VirtualHost *:443> every single time. Must be more a more convenient solutions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with all apache syntax so could please fill out some more information: document root, using WordPress so should it be: /home/exampleuser/public_html/ 

Give me an example for http:// www.example.com/old-path 301 to https:// www.example.com/new-path/> to a clean 1to1 with your solution above.

Does it matter where it's located in the .htaccess? Top, bottom? before Wordpress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>?

Thanks!

Comment: my solution is for config file

Comment: I see, unfortunately this site is on a shared hosting since we yet do not want to migrate it to our own server. So we do not have SSH access to control the config.

Comment: sorry I cannot test it, smth like `RewriteEngine On   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old-path   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/new-path/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: still the same chain, flushed cache and but still keep on seeing the chain.

Comment: If I disable force https it works but then the pages that only change protocol from http to https redirect millions of times and crash.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# BEGIN Force http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# END Force http to https
</IfModule>

Comment: wait a moment - did you try **one**  `RewriteCond` and **one** `RewriteRule` that I wrote, or you wrote in addition some rule for force https?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-includes
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old-page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This setup works, but how do I add more URI's to do it in scale instead of adding 20-50 's?

How do URI for index/home page look? Since it's the root /. What would be instead of wp-includes or old-page as folder there?